# Uninstall managed package but retain custom fields and data

Tags: managed-package, custom-field

I have a managed package installed which comes with a few custom fields on standard objects, I want to uninstall this package but keep these fields and the data in them.

Is there a simpler way to do this than creating new custom fields and copying the data from the package's custom fields to my custom fields for every record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really, no. Your only other option I can see is to use the [export file](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.distribution_uninstalling_packages.htm&type=5) created when you uninstall the package to re-load the data into different fields.

You can't keep the package fields. Any way you slice it, you'll have to perform a data migration.

Comment: Thought this might be the case, thanks for the speedy answer!